# Access Uncaptured Proc Arguments

Tags: ruby

Can I access uncaptured arguments to an invoked ruby Proc?
Ruby Procs are very much like JavaScript functions. In Javascript, I can do `arguments[someIndex]`. Is there a ruby version of this?

```
my_proc = Proc.new { |a| p a } #This captures the first argument but not the second
my_proc.call(42,43)
#Can I still access the second argument without capturing it (|a,b|) (with something some kind of a ruby equivalent to `arguments[1]` or doing anything within the pipes)?
```

(Why I'm asking: I've written myself a `strace`-based dependency-tracking `sh` replacement for `rake` and if I am to use it in a `Rake` task, it needs to know what task to assign the discovered dependencies to. In other words, it needs access to the first argument to the task block in which it is invoked, but I don't want it to depend on the first argument always being captured in a particular way.)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: `my_proc = Proc.new { |*a| p a }` splat does exactly what you want.

Comment: wrap arguments into array `my_proc.call([42,43])`.  When you can do `my_proc = Proc.new { |a| p a[1] }`

Comment: @Зелёный No, please, don’t invent wheels. Splat perfectly does the same thing absolutely transparently for a caller.

Comment: @mudasobwa it is just suggestion. **not a answer**.

Comment: @Зелёный I just noted that this is an erroneous suggestion, a matter of bad design.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks. It doesn't solve my problem, but I should've been  clearer. I've added an explanation of what I need it for, but I guess I'll have to solve it in another way as it seems there's probably no counterpart to `arguments`(js) in ruby.

Comment: @PSkocik Splat argument is **exact** counterpart to `arguments` in js.

Comment: @mudasobwa the difference being that you have to include it ahead of time in your method signature. If you don't, there is no way (I am aware of) to access the other arguments after the fact.

Comment: @janfoeh Yes, splat is to be denoted explicitly, while `arguments` are available implicitly. Besides that (OP writes his code himself) it is an exact counterpart. The question was whether splat supports zero-length arguments. It does. So here we go :)

Comment: @mudasobwa the question was whether you can access uncaptured arguments. The answer is _no, but you can use a splat to make sure there are no uncaptured arguments_ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby does not have an equivalent to Javascripts `arguments` accessor. As @mudasobwa noted, you will have to use the splat operator in order to "soak" up all remaining arguments, if you wish to access them at a later time:

```
my_proc = Proc.new { |expected_arg1, expected_arg2, *rest| p expected_arg1 }
```

Use a double-splat when using keyword arguments:

```
my_proc = Proc.new { |expected_arg1:, **rest| p expected_arg1 }
```